# Running video while decrypting it Android

Tags: android, aes, exoplayer, mediacontroller

I'm a newbie in android, i want to run offline video encrypted by AES, by EXOPlayer / MediaController. Because of the time to decrypt this video(>100MB) too slow, i want to solve this problem by running video while decrypting. Can anyone have any idea about code or library in Android to help solving this issue?

Comment: could decrypting and storing back be an option? or encrypting it using a lighter algorithm?

Comment: sorry, could you suggest any encryption's algorithm lighter than AES in android. I use AES just because it's popular @10101010

Comment: Is it already encrypted with AES or you need to select one?
Decrypting AES looks like a resource-intensive process..
Is there a purpose for encrypting and decrypting this?
Lastly, you can use small key size of AES..